# Single page app that display all site collections , subsite , all lists in ul li (like sitemap)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, spservices, sp.js

I want to make sharepoint hosted application.

Is this possible to get all site collections and all sub sites and all list in tree view structure within app. Please provide some techniques how to achieve this.

I saw an chrome extension FlyView for sharepoint I want to make like this.

Comment: Refer this to get data from hostweb:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickpinheiro/2015/01/30/build-a-sharepoint-hosted-app-to-access-list-data-in-your-host-web-using-the-rest-api-in-10-easy-steps/